# Почему не удаляется файл методом модуля Pathlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Мне нужно удалить файл на Python3. Для этого я выбрал модуль **pathlib** и выполнил следующий код:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = 'C:/Users/101ap/Desktop/Player/picture1.png'

Path.unlink(path)
```

После чего получил ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_closed'

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что делаю неправильно?

Comment: `path = Path('C:/Users/101ap/Desktop/Player/picture1.png')` ?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('C:/Users/101ap/Desktop/Player/picture1.png')
path.unlink()
```